# PayPal IPN Cart Quantities don't exist?

Tags: paypal, checkout, cart, paypal-ipn

Out of all the variables passed from PayPal's IPN cart checkout message, why don't quantities exist for each item? I currently only have the variable **num_cart_items**, which helps indicate how many items they checked out with, but there is no variable for each item describing the quantity of each purchased.

Any help is greatly appreciated with this!

Thanks :)

Comment: You have to send itemized details in your payment in order for them to come back in IPN.  Are you working with Payments Standard, Express Checkout, or what?

Comment: Hi Andrew! I'm working with PayPal express checkout (just sending direct POST payments to PayPal of a cart)

Comment: You need to make sure you're sending all of the itemized details in your DoExpressCheckoutPayment call in order for them to show up in IPN.  Can you post a sample of your API request?

Comment: Andrew, I'm actually not using PayPal's new API, I'm using the instructions listed on this page to post my shopping carts content (https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/howto_checkout-outside). Here are the only variables that PayPal is returning at the moment with my IPN listener: mc_gross, protection_eligibility, payer_id, tax, payment_date, payment_status, charset, mc_shipping, mc_handling, first_name, mc_fee, notify_version, custom, payer_status, business, and num_cart_items. Appears there are a lot of variables left out, likely because of the dated method I use to post my cart.

Comment: Ok, well that's not technically Express Checkout.  That's [Payments Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/wp_standard_overview/) with the [Cart Upload Method](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/).  That link is updated and covers adding individual item details around the middle of the page.

Comment: Payments Standard isn't out-dated, it's just a different way to do things from the API's.  I wasn't talking about the new REST API either, though.  I was talking about the classic Express Checkout API which is what I thought you were using when you said you're using express checkout.  Payments Standard will work just fine once you get the itemized details included.

Comment: Hi Andrew, here is a screenshot of what the form looks like:http://i.imgur.com/lWOpfmc.jpg, which I believe is following the guidelines found in the link I posted earlier. Thanks for all the help you've provided thus far! :) Hopefully looking at my form will help a bit.

Comment: Can you please provide with a sample of the result HTML instead of including the PHP stuff in there?

Comment: Also, please provide it in text format so I can copy it and play with it on my test server.

Comment: Hi Andrew, here is the form with a test product: http://pastebin.com/7qJ27KdN

Answer (score 0):

I tested with your code and made a slight adjustment to add an additional item.  I'm also on the sandbox instead of the live server.

The following code worked just fine for me, which again, is basically your code.

```
<form name="paypalSubmit" method="POST" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="sandbo_1111111@angelleye.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="image_url" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Xbox Live 12 Month Gold">
  <input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="1.00">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Test Widget 2">
  <input type="hidden" name="quantity_2" value="5">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="5.00">
  <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
  <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
  <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="../">
  <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
  <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif" alt="Pay now with PayPal!">
</form>
```

That resulted in the following IPN hitting my server.

```
Array
(
    [mc_gross] => 28.54
    [protection_eligibility] => Ineligible
    [item_number1] => 
    [tax] => 2.54
    [item_number2] => 
    [payer_id] => E7BTGVXBFSUAU
    [payment_date] => 02:14:13 May 29, 2013 PDT
    [payment_status] => Completed
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [mc_shipping] => 0.00
    [mc_handling] => 0.00
    [first_name] => Drew
    [mc_fee] => 1.13
    [notify_version] => 3.7
    [custom] => 
    [payer_status] => verified
    [business] => sandbo_1111111@angelleye.com
    [num_cart_items] => 2
    [mc_handling1] => 0.00
    [mc_handling2] => 0.00
    [verify_sign] => AWRBYJcBybrYpBI1KkvirwZh2gF5A8KmDftB0jwwIJb8qnifB-Ur32ZE
    [payer_email] => sandbo_2222222@angelleye.com
    [mc_shipping1] => 0.00
    [mc_shipping2] => 0.00
    [tax1] => 0.00
    [tax2] => 0.00
    [contact_phone] => 747-668-4003
    [txn_id] => 03N63014BS023794T
    [payment_type] => instant
    [payer_business_name] => Drew Angell's Test Store
    [last_name] => Angell
    [item_name1] => Xbox Live 12 Month Gold
    [receiver_email] => sandbo_1111111@angelleye.com
    [item_name2] => Test Widget 2
    [payment_fee] => 1.13
    [quantity1] => 1
    [quantity2] => 5
    [receiver_id] => ATSCG2QMC9KAU
    [txn_type] => cart
    [mc_gross_1] => 1.00
    [mc_currency] => USD
    [mc_gross_2] => 25.00
    [residence_country] => US
    [test_ipn] => 1
    [transaction_subject] => Shopping CartXbox Live 12 Month GoldTest Widget 2
    [payment_gross] => 28.54
    [ipn_track_id] => e46d696f3e2a
)
```

As you can see, the IPN data includes variables for the individual item names and qty's as expected.  If you're not getting this same thing can you post a sample of your raw IPN data?

Comment: Hi Andrew, here is the response that I get from PayPal's sandbox server: http://pastebin.com/NJjNMsdu. Really odd that PayPal is only sending me such a limited amount of variables when our forms hardly differ.. Thanks again for helping me along this far and your continued assistance!